# Where to Download Missing Textures

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, texture-painting

Where can I find the missing textures for Blender? You see, I'm trying to color a model of a little girl for Tina in the 3D remake of Barney and the Backyard Gang's Three Wishes video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ceD2VJ3_GTI

[image]

Comment: Those aren't missing textures for blender. That means that the model you downloaded is supposed to include textures that weren't there.

Comment: might be the textures are included but the paths do not match where they are on your system. Simply put, Blender can see there should be images files for the object but can not load them. The system console may detail what the paths it is looking in are.